# Tkinter <Enter> bind looping forever

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am tring to make a selectable clock face for events. I have my Canvas object and created a bunch of circles with text inside them.

I am wanting to invert the colour of the circle and text when the mouse is hovering over.

The issues are:

- Leave detectected when entering text inside circle.
- Moving too fast causes a repeting Enter/Leave loop which crashes the program.

code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from math import sin, cos, pi
root = Tk()

class TimePicker(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.tformat = kwargs.pop('format', 24)
        self.width, self.height, self.radious = kwargs['width'], kwargs['height'], rd = (kwargs.pop('radious', 100)*2, )*3
        self.radious /=4
        assert self.tformat in [12, 24], "Time Format must be '12' or '24'"
        super(TimePicker, self).__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.active_line = None
        self.create_center_circle(self.width/2, self.height/2, self.radious*2, fill="white", outline="#000", width=1)
        self.circle_numbers(self.width/2, self.height/2, self.radious+5, 10, [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 'Helvetica 11 bold', "Hours")
        self.circle_numbers(self.width/2, self.height/2, self.radious*2-15, 10, [0, 15, 30, 45], 'Helvetica 11 bold', "Minutes")

    def create_center_circle(self, x, y, r, **kwargs):
        return super().create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)
    def create_circle_arc(self, x, y, r, **kwargs):
        if "start" in kwargs and "end" in kwargs:
            kwargs["extent"] = kwargs["end"] - kwargs["start"]
            del kwargs["end"]
        return super().create_arc(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)
    def circle_numbers(self, x: int, y: int, r: int, cr:int, numbers: list, font: str, tp:str):
        _angle = 360/len(numbers)
        for n in numbers:
            ax =  r * sin(pi * 2 * (360-_angle*n-180) / 360);
            ay = r * cos(pi * 2 * (360-_angle*n-180) / 360);
            tag = f'{tp}:{str(n)}'
            cl = self.create_center_circle(x+ax, y+ay, cr, fill="white", outline="#000", width=1, tag=tag)
            tx = self.create_text(x+ax, y+ay, text=str(n).zfill(2), fill="black", font=(font), tag='tx'+tag )
            self.tag_bind(f'{tp}:{str(n)}', '<Enter>', lambda e=Event(), c=(x+ax, y+ay), t=tag, s=True: self._hover(e, c, s, t))
            self.tag_bind(f'{tp}:{str(n)}', '<Leave>', lambda e=Event(), c=(x+ax, y+ay), t=tag, s=False: self._hover(e, c, s, t))
            self.tag_bind(f'{tp}:{str(n)}', '<Button-1>', lambda e=Event(), c=cl, s=tx, n=n, t=tp,: self._set_number(e, c, s, n, t))

    def _hover(self, event, coords, state, tag):
        print('hover')
        if state: # If hovering inside the object
            print("hovering")
            cl =event.widget.find_withtag(tag) ## for the text and circle with the hovered tag
            tx = event.widget.find_withtag('tx'+tag)
            self.itemconfigure(cl, fill='black')
            self.itemconfigure(tx, fill="white")
            self.active_line = self.create_line(self.width/2, self.height/2, coords[0], coords[1], fill="black", width=2) ##create new line
        else: ##If left the object
            print("exited")
            if self.active_line is not None: ##if there is a line
                cl = event.widget.find_withtag(tag) ## for the text and circle in the tag
                tx = event.widget.find_withtag('tx'+tag)
                self.itemconfigure(cl, fill='white')
                self.itemconfigure(tx, fill="black")
                self.delete(self.active_line)
                self.active_line = None

    def _set_number(self, event, cl, tx, number, tp):
        print('set', cl, tx, number, tp)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    tp=TimePicker(root, format=24, background="red", radious=100)
    tp.pack(side=TOP)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You'll notice that if you move the mouse _very slowly_ into the very edge of one of the number circles, the enter event is triggered and the highlighting works correctly. Apparently `tkinter` is only counting `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events on the _border_ of the circle; that's why `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` are immediately triggered in succession. The cursor is entering then leaving the 1-pixel-wide border. Unfortunately I don't have a solution for this problem yet... it's rather strange given that circles can be filled in.

Comment: i managed to find a solution. it was taking into account the full circle as an `<Enter>` event and going into the text as a `<Leave>` event. My issue was the creation of the line. As that line intersected the mouse it acted as a `<Leave>` event which deleted the line which acted as a `<Enter>` event which of course created the line and looped forever event after moving the mouse (this is why its also an intermittent issue) the solution is to reduce the line so it ends up not intersecting the circle and causing loops.

Comment: That's good! Please write and accept an answer now that you've found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I realised when testing that when creating a line and that line happened to be under the mouse cursor the event for `<Leave>` would be triggered for the Text, this then deleted the line causing an `<Enter>` event drawing the line under the cursor again.

The solution to this was to make the line shorter and not allowing it to enter the same space as the mouse.

As a quick fix i have made the line shorter by 20%, however a complete solution would require checking if the line is under the mouse and triggering a flag to prevent the line from being destroyed.

```py
    def _hover(self, event, coords, state, tag):
        ...
        self.itemconfigure(tx, fill="white")
        dx = (1 - 0.8) * self.width/2 + 0.8 * coords[0]
        dy = (1 - 0.8) * self.height/2 + 0.8 * coords[1]
        self.active_line = self.create_line(self.width/2, self.height/2, dx, dy, fill="#0797FF", width=2, tag=None) ##create new line
```